# Updating core data when a timer in custom cell is done?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, timer, custom-cell

I'm trying to update my core data when the timer in my custom cell is done counting down. To do this, I want to save the Managed Objects ID in the cell, and then send it back to the datasource when the timer is done to get it updated. I'm still kinda new to Swift, so bear with me if I've made some fundamental mistakes already.

First of all, my timer is activated like this, this is also where I'm sending the object ID.

```
    func longPressActive(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began){
            println("STATE BEGAN")
            var point = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.tv)
            if let indexPath = self.tv.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point){

                let data = messageList[indexPath.row] as Messages

                if let theCell = self.tv.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? TableViewCell{
                    theCell.timerStarted()

                var objectID:NSManagedObjectID = NSManagedObjectID()
                objectID.setValue(data, forKey: "messageType")
                    theCell.objectID = objectID
                }
}
}
```

In the cell it looks like this:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelOutl: UILabel!

    var counter = 10
    private var timer = NSTimer()
    var objectID: NSManagedObjectID = NSManagedObjectID()

    func timerStarted(){

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func update(){
        if counter > 0{
        counter = --counter
            println(counter)}
        else{
        println("timer done")
        timer.invalidate()

        let VC:ViewController = ViewController()
        VC.updateObject(objectID)
        }
    }
}
```

Where my updateObject-function will look something like this:

```
func updateObject(identity: NSManagedObjectID){
    //Retrieve object ID from cell and set it's "read" value to true.
}
```

Does this look somewhat correct? Can you save an objects ID like that and reuse it later? If it looks okay, please help me with the content of the last function where I need to use the object ID again.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work?

Comment: @MartinR I don't know how to retrieve the object ID in the last function, so if this seems right that's the only thing missing.

Comment: `objectID.setValue(data, forKey: "messageType")` looks *very* suspicious to me and will probably crash. What do you expect it to do? Did you test if that works? – Then `let VC:ViewController = ViewController()` creates a *new* view controller instance which is completely unrelated to the existing view controller. – So my answer to your question *"Does this look somewhat correct?"* is "No".

Comment: To add to @MartinR's comments, I would reconsider using the cell to set and respond to the timer.  You will face significant problems with cells being reused (so that the cell may relate to a different row by the time the timer fires).  Have your table view controller do that work, and update the cell if necessary.

Comment: @pbasdf The answer to this may be too obvious but; You say I need to let my table view controller take care of it, but I do not have a tableViewController connected to the viewController with the tableView.

Comment: @frank21 Sure, I meant "the view controller that manages your tableView" rather than a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Your view controller - whether it is a subclass of `UIViewController` or `UITableviewController` - needs to manage the data model.  A tableview cell is simply a window onto the data model - it is a transient object and shouldn't be used to store any data or state

Comment: @Paulw11 so if I tried to store the object ID in the cell it would be deleted once the cell was reloaded again?

Comment: Yes - cell objects can get reused when the tableView scrolls - a cell that is offscreen is reused for a row that is on screen